# How can I read a file word by word using stdio.h in C?

Tags: c, string, cpu-word, stdio

I'm new to C and I can't quite get it without a segmentation fault.

Here's my idea so far:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

char *nextWord(FILE *stream) {
    char *word;
    char c;

    while ( (c = (char)fgetc(stream)) != ' ' && c != '\n' && c != '\0') {
        strcat(word, &c);
    }

    return word;
}

int main() {
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen("testppm.ppm", "r");
    char *word;
    word = nextWord(f);
    printf("%s",word);
}
```

Comment: strcat is not what you want.  After you follow Chris's advice and have word pointing to an actual buffer, you should just do something like word[ i++ ] = c;  (Or, typically, *word++ = c and have another pointer keeping track of the beginning of the buffer)

Answer (score 1):

In your `nextWord` function, you never initialize the local variable `word` to point at anything, so when you try to write to the pointed-at memory with `strcat`, you get a segfault.

You need to allocate memory to store the word that you are going to read.  The problem is, you don't know how big that word will be, so you don't know how much space to allocate.  There are a number of possible approaches:

- Use a (large) fixed size buffer on the stack to hold the word as you read it, then copy it to a malloc'd area of the appropriate size when you return it.  There will be problems if you encounter a word that is too big for your fixed size buffer.
- allocate a small block to read the word into, and keep track of how much is used as you read characters.  When the block is full, realloc it to be bigger.

Answer (score -1):

Or you can also use the fscanf function in your while loop.

```
 char *nextWord(FILE *stream) {  
    char *buffer[124], *word;
     int previous_size = 0;

     while(!feof(!stream)){
         int n = fscanf(file, "%s", buffer);
         if(word == NULL){
            word = malloc(sizeof(char)*n)
         } else {
           realloc(word, n + previous_size);
         }
         strncat(word, buffer, strlen(buffer) - 1);        
         previous_size = n;
      }
      return word;

 }
```

A little explanation. The function **fscanf** returns the number of characters read. So the first thing i do is to save that value. If **word** is NULL you allocate it with the number of character otherwise you allocate word with the **previous_size** variable. 
Don't forget to flush the **buffer** variable

Comment: Don't use `fscanf` to read a string of unknown length into a fixed-size buffer. You want to use a function where you can specify the size of the buffer.

Comment: -1: this will pretty much always crash as fscanf returns the number of items matched (generally always 1 in this example) and not the length of anything read.  Also, if the word is too long for the buffer, bad things will happen.